# use a variable's value before change it - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I use a variable's value before I change it in the same line.
I want some thing like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display = this == "none"? "initial" : "none";
```

something in the place of "this" to refer to that variable's value, without repeating the name/path or whatever it's called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you calling this code ?

Comment: @Agalo it's part of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Use variables:

```
var el = document.getElementById("id");
var display = el.style.display;

el.style.display = display == "none" ? "initial" : "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression so you assign variables on the fly. With ES6 arrow syntax, that looks like this:

```js
((t,k) => t[k] = t[k] == "none"? "initial" : "none")
                           (document.getElementById("id").style, 'display');
```

```html
A word is <span id="id">not</span> hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the requirement in place, but here is a sample snippet to help you with:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  setInterval(function() { // To have some effect on display

    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display =

      (function() {
        var display = document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display;
        return display;
      })() // Self invoke

    == "none" ? "block" : "none"; // Manage

  }, 1000);

}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="myDivClass" style="display: none">Hello!</div>
```

---

Using [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
setInterval(function() { // To have some effect on display
  var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");

  element.style.display =

    (() => {
      return element.style.display;
    })() // Self invoke

  == "none" ? "block" : "none"; // Manage

}, 1000);
```

```css
#myDiv {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="myDivClass" style="display: none">Hello!</div>
```